# Access Tables and Calculations

Tags: ms-access

I have four fields in Access that are all yes/no. I want to create a new field that performs a calculation based off: If all four fields are yes then show yes or else show no. Does anyone have an idea about how I can go about this?

Regards

Comment: You're wanting a MSSQL query I take it?

Comment: I would like to be able to add a calculated field and enter an Expression into Expression builder that returns a yes/no value.

Comment: I am just in Access DBMS. I want to check yes or no on four fields and when all four fields are checked I want a new field to check to yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create 4 fields with type Yes/No
2. Create Field5 as Calculated Field -> Yes/No
3. In the ExpressionBuilder put the formula

   IIf([Field1] And [Field2] And [Field3] And [Field4],1,0)
4. Test it :)

Comment: This seems better with regards to the yes/no type let me examine this, ty.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to do this on a button event, or a gotfocus event?  Either way, the field would be equal to: IIF(Field1 = "Yes" and Field2 = "Yes and Field3 = "Yes" and Field4 = "Yes", "Yes", "No")

Comment: Okay this seems like something I am looking for let me give it a try.

Comment: Judging by what you wrote above, you may need to put that in the AfterUpdate event on all 4 fields.  This way, no matter which order you check them off in, you'll get your answer.  Of course, you'd have to default all 4 fields to "No", so that when the user changes it to "Yes" it will re-run the AfterUpdate event.