# Yes/No Calculation Based Off Of Other Tables Record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having an issue calculating a column in one table based off of another tables records value. So here is the layout:

tblContainers:

```
Container  IsRented
00-0033    Yes  
00-0044    No
```

tblRentals:

```
Customer   IsRenting   Container
Brian      Yes         00-0044
Jake       No          00-0033
```

So tblContainers contains all of the containers, tblRentals contains all of the rental history for the company. As you can see the containers are referenced in both tables, as well as the renting. So if in tblRentals, a container that is listed has a yes in the IsRenting column, then in tblContainers, IsRented will be switched to yes. So in this example above, in tblContainers, IsRented for container 00-0033 would be changed to No, and IsRented for 00-0044 would be changed to Yes.

I have found others like this, however, they're based on sums.I will reference the others below to see if they help you guys help me out.

References:

[Calculate a field's value based on multiple records in another table in Access DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804169/calculate-a-fields-value-based-on-multiple-records-in-another-table-in-access-d)

[I need to calculate values for a record in a database based off of other values in other records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061391/i-need-to-calculate-values-for-a-record-in-a-database-based-off-of-other-values)

This last one is similar but only on the same table, it's not crossing tables.

[Access Tables and Calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796135/access-tables-and-calculations)

Comment: What is your actual desired output here?  Each of the two tables has state for rented, but whose version do you want to select?

Comment: Tim, I am trying to change tblContainers IsRented to Yes or No based off of tblRentals IsRenting field value.

Comment: Also, just as a twist.. The tblRentals is a HISTORY table, so in the container's column in the tblRentals there will be multiple times where the same container may be listed because it has gone on multiple rentals at different times... So really I am looking to see if tblContainers's container is in the tblRentals table and if it is, is there a row that contains the container AND a "yes" in the IsRenting field... Wow I hope I didn't make that confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to use an `update` statement with a `join`:

```
update tblContainers as c
   inner join tblRentals as r on c.container = r.container 
set c.IsRented = r.IsRented
```

Comment: When I was researching this, that is what I was thinking something along the join statements. Will this still work if there are two rows that contain the same container # but one is yes and one is no? I would want yes to appear if that happened.

Comment: This worked! I am assuming since it updates the rows starting at 1 and works it's way down to the last row it worked perfectly!

Thank you very much!